# Java JFreeChart: customize tooltip screen position

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jfreechart

I implemented my own JFreeChart `XYToolTipGenerator` and, as the chart it is used on is almost full screen, sometimes the tooltip position (on screen) hides the point it is related to (e.g. in the bottom right corner, since it seems that tooltip is configured to be positioned South-East of the mouse / data point). This is a problem because the user needs to be able to click on the chart's data points (as it generates a specific action).

Is there a way to either define dynamically the position of the tooltip (e.g. for data points bottom right I would ask the tooltip to be shown North-West) or, alternatively, to define a systematic position (e.g. North-West instead of South-East as it is by default)?

This problem has given me headaches for the last few days - any help or hint is more than welcome.

Many thanks!
Thomas

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116912).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer I posted on the [JFreeChart forum](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116912):

> JFreeChart is using the standard Swing tool tip mechanism. In the ChartPanel class, the [getToolTipText(mouseEvent)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getToolTipText%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) method is overridden to return the appropriate text for the tooltip, and that's it.
>
> Swing also gives you the option to override the [getToolTipLocation(mouseEvent)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getToolTipLocation%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) method, and that's probably what you need here.

Comment: Is this still accurate?  I extended ChartPanel and overrode the getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent) method and it did not even get called.  I'm using JFreeChart 1.5.3 with JDK 17.0.6 on a mac.

Comment: As far as I know, yes; more discussion [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/discussions/347).